# Why is WSARecv erroring with WSAEFAULT in gRPC?

Tags: c++, sockets, grpc, winsock2, grpc-c++

We've been debugging an issue where our gRPC connection is getting shutdown ([Any ideas why we're getting Intermittent gRPC Unavailable/Unknown RpcExceptions (C++/C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955457/any-ideas-why-were-getting-intermittent-grpc-unavailable-unknown-rpcexceptions)) and have found that the following call is returning WSAEFAULT:

```
  status = WSARecv(tcp->socket->socket, buffers, (DWORD)tcp->read_slices->count,
                   &bytes_read, &flags, &info->overlapped, NULL);
```

Context of the call will be at the bottom of this post.

This happens intermittently, resulting in a disconnection. We initially suspected something memory related, however we added tracing of the buffers & count before and after the call and the memory doesn't appear to be corrupted. Weirdly, we have found that if we zero out the buffers and then call WSARecv a second time, the call is successful 99% of the time. Simply retrying and retrying with sleeps doesn't have the same effect.

1. Any ideas on what might be causing the WSAEFAULT?
2. When we turned on Winsock tracing, we see the following traced - does anyone know why it would output 0x0 for buffer length & size when this isn't the case tracing the same address with grpc tracing?:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Winsock-AFD" Guid="{e53c6823-7bb8-44bb-90dc-3f86090d48a6}" />
        <EventID>1004</EventID>
        <Version>0</Version>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <Task>1004</Task>
        <Opcode>12</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x8000000000000006</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-09-01T18:26:52.247424500-05:00" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{533ee2b0-da8f-ffff-0000-000000000000}" />
        <Execution ProcessID="3368" ThreadID="772" ProcessorID="3" KernelTime="5820" UserTime="6780" />
        <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Winsock-AFD/Operational</Channel>
        <Computer />
    </System>
    <EventData>
        <Data Name="EnterExit">       0</Data>
        <Data Name="Location">    4005</Data>
        <Data Name="Process">0xFFFFDA8F510ED080</Data>
        <Data Name="Endpoint">0xFFFFDA8F554FA0B0</Data>
        <Data Name="BufferCount">       0</Data>
        <Data Name="Buffer">0x0</Data>
        <Data Name="BufferLength">       0</Data>
        <Data Name="Status">0xC0000005</Data>
    </EventData>
    <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
        <Level>Error </Level>
        <Opcode>Connected </Opcode>
        <Keywords>
            <Keyword>Stream socket </Keyword>
            <Keyword>Winsock initiated event </Keyword>
        </Keywords>
        <Task>AfdReceive</Task>
        <Message>recv: 0: Process 0xFFFFDA8F510ED080, Endpoint 0xFFFFDA8F554FA0B0, Buffer Count 0, Buffer 0x0, Length 0, Seq 4005, Status The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s. </Message>
        <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Winsock Network Event/Operational </Channel>
        <Provider>Microsoft-Windows-Winsock Network Event </Provider>
    </RenderingInfo>
</Event>
```

```
#define DEFAULT_TARGET_READ_SIZE 8192
#define MAX_WSABUF_COUNT 16
static void win_read(grpc_endpoint* ep, grpc_slice_buffer* read_slices,
                     grpc_closure* cb, bool urgent) {
  grpc_tcp* tcp = (grpc_tcp*)ep;
  grpc_winsocket* handle = tcp->socket;
  grpc_winsocket_callback_info* info = &handle->read_info;
  int status;
  DWORD bytes_read = 0;
  DWORD flags = 0;
  WSABUF buffers[MAX_WSABUF_COUNT];
  size_t i;

  if (grpc_tcp_trace.enabled()) {
    gpr_log(GPR_INFO, "TCP:%p win_read", tcp);
  }

  if (tcp->shutting_down) {
    grpc_core::ExecCtx::Run(
        DEBUG_LOCATION, cb,
        GRPC_ERROR_CREATE_REFERENCING_FROM_STATIC_STRING(
            "TCP socket is shutting down", &tcp->shutdown_error, 1));
    return;
  }

  tcp->read_cb = cb;
  tcp->read_slices = read_slices;
  grpc_slice_buffer_reset_and_unref_internal(read_slices);
  grpc_slice_buffer_swap(read_slices, &tcp->last_read_buffer);

  if (tcp->read_slices->length < DEFAULT_TARGET_READ_SIZE / 2 &&
      tcp->read_slices->count < MAX_WSABUF_COUNT) {
    // TODO(jtattermusch): slice should be allocated using resource quota
    grpc_slice_buffer_add(tcp->read_slices,
                          GRPC_SLICE_MALLOC(DEFAULT_TARGET_READ_SIZE));
  }

  GPR_ASSERT(tcp->read_slices->count <= MAX_WSABUF_COUNT);
  for (i = 0; i < tcp->read_slices->count; i++) {
    buffers[i].len = (ULONG)GRPC_SLICE_LENGTH(
        tcp->read_slices->slices[i]);  // we know slice size fits in 32bit.
    buffers[i].buf = (char*)GRPC_SLICE_START_PTR(tcp->read_slices->slices[i]);
  }

  TCP_REF(tcp, "read");

  /* First let's try a synchronous, non-blocking read. */
  status = WSARecv(tcp->socket->socket, buffers, (DWORD)tcp->read_slices->count,
                   &bytes_read, &flags, NULL, NULL);
  info->wsa_error = status == 0 ? 0 : WSAGetLastError();

  /* Did we get data immediately ? Yay. */
  if (info->wsa_error != WSAEWOULDBLOCK) {
    info->bytes_transferred = bytes_read;
    grpc_core::ExecCtx::Run(DEBUG_LOCATION, &tcp->on_read, GRPC_ERROR_NONE);
    return;
  }

  /* Otherwise, let's retry, by queuing a read. */
  memset(&tcp->socket->read_info.overlapped, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
  status = WSARecv(tcp->socket->socket, buffers, (DWORD)tcp->read_slices->count,
                   &bytes_read, &flags, &info->overlapped, NULL);

  if (status != 0) {
    int wsa_error = WSAGetLastError();
    if (wsa_error != WSA_IO_PENDING) {
      info->wsa_error = wsa_error;
      grpc_core::ExecCtx::Run(DEBUG_LOCATION, &tcp->on_read,
                              GRPC_WSA_ERROR(info->wsa_error, "WSARecv"));
      return;
    }
  }

  grpc_socket_notify_on_read(tcp->socket, &tcp->on_read);
}
```

Comment: The error `WSAEFAULT` is pretty blunt: "The lpBuffers parameter is not completely contained in a valid part of the user address space." meaning that either the size parameter or the buffer is not valid in some way and is causing an access violation. Have you tried just allocating a buffer the old dumb way? Yes it's not zero copy but at least it would isolate out the GRPC stuff from winsock.

Comment: @Mgetz I just went ahead and tried that out (new'd up my own temporary buffers to pass into WSARecv calls, copy the results to the grpc slices, delete the temporary buffers and still got the same WSAEFAULT on the overlapped call to WSARecv.

What we're still a little confused about is how the overlapped call can fail but then zero'ing out the buffers and re-trying can succeed most of the time.

Comment: Actually it makes sense... when you allocate memory it doesn't always get immediately added as an active page in the process. When you malloc+memset that forces the page fault which ensures the page is present.